# Get list of all ids in an xPage container control

Tags: xpages

I am using this code to copy some documents by a button click [source](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/ad18d9bdca1141b1852576e8004ca5a1?OpenDocument). I would like to prevent the end user from having to select columns and would prefer simply get all the documents ids from the view panel. Not exactly sure how to do that, or if a dataview might be a better choice for me.

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1"); //get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); //get the array of document ids
for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length;i++){
var docId=docIDArray[i];

var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
var db=session.getCurrentDatabase();
var newDoc:NotesDocument=doc.copyToDatabase(db);
newDoc.replaceItemValue("approved","No");
var id=newDoc.getUniversalID();
newDoc.save(true);

}
```

Comment: So you want to copy all documents that display in the view, rather than only the ones selected by the user?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like a simple thing so I am going to assume I a missing something simple here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the view panel out of the equation: a view panel is a component, and components are for users to interact with; if the user's interaction with the view panel (i.e. "selecting" documents) doesn't alter which documents you wish to duplicate, ignore the view panel (at least, for the purposes of this specific event).

If you simply want to duplicate all documents that display in the view to which the view panel is bound, talk to the same data source the view panel is associated with. So, assuming your data source declaration looks something like the following:

```
<xp:panel>
 <xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoView var="allDocuments" viewName="($All)" />
 </xp:this.data>
 <xp:viewPanel value="#{allDocuments}">
 ...
```

...then just iterate through that same view:

```
allDocuments.setAutoUpdate(false);
var eachDoc = allDocuments.getFirstDocument();
while(eachDoc) {
 var newDoc = eachDoc.copyToDatabase(database);
 newDoc.replaceItemValue("approved", "No");
 newDoc.save();
 newDoc.recycle();
 var nextDoc = allDocuments.getNextDocument(eachDoc);
 eachDoc.recycle();
 eachDoc = nextDoc;
}
allDocuments.setAutoUpdate(true);
```

Since you're duplicating the documents within the same database, when the event finishes, the view panel will simply show twice as many documents, since you duplicated all of them. Unless, of course, the item value you're replacing disqualifies them from the view you're displaying.

**NOTE 1:** The reason the code above toggles the `autoUpdate` property is because, unless you toggle that to `false` prior to the iteration, when you duplicate each document, if the new document *does* display in the view you're iterating, the indexer will become aware of it, and you might end up in an infinite loop, because each time you try to get the next document, it's actually returning a handle on the duplicate you just created... so you would essentially be infinitely duplicating the same document until some exception is thrown (i.e. stack overflow, out of memory, etc.). Disabling `autoUpdate` prevents that by only allowing iteration of entries the index was aware of when your routine began.

**NOTE 2:** If the data source is *only* defined inside the view panel, move it to a parent (panel, Custom Control, or XPage) that also contains whatever component will trigger the duplication (i.e. button, link) and reference the data source within the view panel. That way both the view panel and the button can talk to the same data; otherwise, only the view panel is aware that the data source exists.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That is exactly what I needed. I removed the autoupdate as I am copying a set of master documents that have a specific value, while all copies have a different value so I don't run the risk of looping my copies. I really need to think of the data and not the control... Thanks again for such a quick answer. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Tim: just out of curiosity - had I seen Patrick's question earlier I would have proposed a solution using the "good old" Domino backend classes, i.e. get the view from the db >> use the view's "AllEntries" property as a NotesViewEntryCollection >> iterate through the collection's entries duplicating the ones that indeed are documents (not to forget recycling each BE object as it becomes obsolete). - Trying to learn as much as I can my question is: where would you see the advantage of your approach over mine? Would mine be wasting too many resources?

Comment: For educational purposes I too would like to hear the differences between solutions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the "ideal" way to iterate any view is via a view navigator, as that often yields the best performance. In this case, however, you're not just reading column values; you're getting a handle on every document. You'd need to recycle the view navigator, every view entry, and every document... plus all the duplicate documents you create. Which is the second reason you might as well just iterate documents instead of entries: you're writing to disk for every document... that will be your bottleneck, not iterating the view, so iterating via entries is just wasted optimization.